# not able to solve edge case in number of contiguous subarrays with sum k

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sum, sub-array

I have been trying to solve the "Subarray Sum Equals K" problem on leetcode. However I am not able to solve some test cases with the following code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Solution(object):
    def subarraySum(self, nums, k):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type k: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        sumTable = defaultdict(lambda : 0) 

        count = 0
        totalSum = 0
        for i in range(0,len(nums)):
            totalSum += nums[i]
            if(totalSum==k):
                count += 1
            sumTable[totalSum] += 1

        for key in sumTable:
            # print(key)
            if (key-k) in sumTable:
                    count += sumTable[key-k]

        return count
```

Comment: Umm just put the entire code into a codeblock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution on [Github](https://github.com/kyle8998/LeetCode/blob/master/Python/subarray-sum-equals-k.py)

```
import collections
class Solution(object):
    def subarraySum(self, nums, k):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type k: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        result = 0
        accumulated_sum = 0
        lookup = collections.defaultdict(int)
        lookup[0] += 1
        for num in nums:
            accumulated_sum += num
            result += lookup[accumulated_sum - k]
            lookup[accumulated_sum] += 1
        return result
```

Adding on why your solution won't work, is because your TotalSum never resets. Therefore you detect either 0 or 1 solutions.